# Svelte compiler gives me an error in my "Icon" component file while building. What could be a possible error?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

This is my "Icon" component file

```
<script>
    export let { href, brand, anim, color} = '';
    let icon;

    function addClass(){
        icon.classList.add(anim, color);
    }

    function removeClass(){
        icon.classList.remove(anim, color);
    }
</script>

<a
    {href}
    target="_blank"
    on:mouseenter={addClass}
    on:mouseleave={removeClass}
    class="w-7 h-7 pl-4 first:pl-0 pr-8 grid group"
>
    <i bind:this={icon} class={`fa-brands fa-xl ${brand}`} />
</a>
```

I want the component to take in href, brand, color and anim props. When the user hovers on an anchor tag, it should apply an animation and color.

And this is how I have implemented it in my root page.svelte

`<Icon href="https://www.linkedin.com/" brand="fa-linkedin" anim="fa-beat" color="text-yellow-500" />`

However when I build the project I get this error

file: C:/Users/Dev/frontend projects/svelte-portfolio/src/lib/Icon.svelte
error during build:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reassigned')
at file:///C:/Users/Dev/frontend%20projects/svelte-portfolio/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/Component.js:1351:13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of playing around in the repl, it looks like the problem stemmed from you destructuring an export (not that it's not possible, it's definitely possible). But as you probably noticed the first time around, doing so will give an error that says 'complex binding requires initialization'.

You used an empty string `''` as your default value which is a [primitive type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) and primitives in JS are **immutable**. On dev mode it works perfectly fine but breaks on build. I'm assuming there is some svelte code trying to reassign the value but again, they are immutable causing the error.

Here's a repl I used to play around:
https://svelte.dev/repl/37cb75a470a443c3b767ad7d79cdb7b7?version=4.0.0

##### 1st Solution

A simple solution would literally change the default value to anything that is not a [primitive type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive). So an object would suffice:

```html
<script>
    export let { href, brand, anim, color} = {};
    
    ...
</script>
```

or even better having default values for them

##### 2nd Solution

Another solution that I think would be a better one is to instead declare each of those properties as its own, without destructuring it. And it would also help with readability.

```html
<script>
    // you can do something like this for a one liner
    export let href, brand, anim, color;

    // or you can declare them one by one
    export let href;
    export let brand;
    export let anim;
    export let color;

    ...
</script>
```

and again, this is my own opinion, and I don't know about the standards or others' opinions, but I think the second solution is cleaner and prone to less bugs

Comment: Thank you. And I do agree, it looks better without destructuring